# Socket error code 103 when using python's socket lib?

Tags: python, sockets

There is a strange behave when I am trying to use `socket` lib to test if a port is opened on remote host. Here is my code, and I am using python2.6 on centos6.9.

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.settimeout(5)
result = sock.connect_ex((
    remote_host, 80
))
sock.close()
return result == 0
```

The problem is, if `connect_ex` returns `111`(which is `Connection refused`), and then try to reconnect to another port such as `81`, it will return `103`(which is `Software caused connection abort`). The progress is like below:

```
sock.connect_ex((ip, 81)) # return 111
sock.connect_ex((ip, 81)) # return 103
sock.connect_ex((ip, 81)) # return 111
sock.connect_ex((ip, 80)) # return 103
sock.connect_ex((ip, 80)) # return 0
```

So question: why it will return 103 after every failed connect?

Comment: Terminating the socket connection before processing is finished. Timeout  is also a process and should be expected to finished.The connection has been rejected, but you must look for it during the time-out period. That's why you get two error codes.
Also, using a timeout on socket connections causes all errors to be timed out. For this reason, standard TCP packets have time and window information.

Comment: @dsgdfg I didn't fully understand you. First, you say "using a timeout on socket connections causes all errors to be timed out", but actually timeout error code is 110 instead of 111, so why I got 111 but not 110 if you are right? Second, five `connect_ex` return immediately, so I think there shouldn't be a time-out process? Third, is there a reliable way to avoid getting 103?

Comment: If you wait 5 seconds and then close the socket, you will only have a connection rejected error. `sock.settimeout(5)` mean ?

Comment: @dsgdfg Are we talking about one thing? Surely if I wait 5 seconds I will only have an error. But I was testing an unopened port(81). The remote host immediately refused so I got 111. When I tested it again, I got 103 instead of getting 111 again. My question is why I got 103 while it just return immediately and how to avoid?

Comment: **Stop iterate multiple ports with `SINGLE CONNECTION`**, You can't scan multiple ports with a single connection! Which is faster? Do you read buffer memory or create a new connection? You should stop raping the Kernel. The time of opening and closing the socket is a minimum of 200 milliseconds (you can test it yourself). How do you know which process the error message came from?